# File.exists on USB-Stick

Tags: android, usb

I would like to check if a certain file exists on an USB-stick, plugged in over OTG-Adapter. 
Following code returns always false, no matter what happens. The file can be opened when deleting the if clause.

```
File usb_dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File myFile = new File(usb_dir+ "/update.apk");

if (myFile.exists()==true) {
    final Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///mnt/usb_storage/update.apk"), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(promptInstall);

} else if (myFile.exists()==false){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not working!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

even this is not working:

```
 String usb_dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
 File myFile = new File(usb_dir+ "/update.apk");
```

Can anyone help me out there?

Comment: Print what getExternalStorageDirectory() returns.

Comment: usb_dir = /mnt/sdcard

Comment: Then it points to your SD card on the device, not USB stick.

Comment: but if I link to "/mnt/usb_storage/update.apk" directly it is still false and I know that /mnt/usb_storage/update.apk exists and can be open through code.

Comment: It is possible that you dont have permissions to write ext storage in Android Manifest

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> both in manifest